# external style sheet with chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, styles, external

alright, first time asker, i have an issue when using an external style sheet with the chrome browser, which doesn't occur when using Edge and Firefox. it also works correctly in Jsfiddle.
the issue is that it doesn't display background or text colour in my body, but for the header, it works perfectly.

this is my first time using an external style sheet, but i assume since its working in other browsers, this is an issue with compatibility with chrome.

i link the CSS file like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
```

here is my CSS code itself:

```
body {
background-color: Black;
color: Green;
font-family: verdana;  
}

h1 {
text-align: center;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: Green;
}

li {
float: left;
border-right:1px solid #bbb;
}

li:last-child {
border-right: none;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: Black;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #111;
}

.active {
background-color: green;
}
```

thanks in advance for any help you can offer, its for a school esque project with strict criteria, which is why it needs to be external and in chrome.

Comment: Tried clearing the cache? Checked the console for errors?

Comment: hey @j08691 clearing my cache  fixed it. thanks!
why does this work, and will this issue happen with other people as well? if so is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: You could manually alter the path to the CSS file and add a query string which will force the browser to download the latest version. Like `href="styles.css?v=123"` where the part after the `?` should be changed when the CSS changes. There are other methods too. Google CSS bust cache

Comment: @j08691, awesome! 
and finally, how do i show the question as solved/ show your answer if people have the same issue? just to tie it up nicely

Comment: You can just close the question, I'm sure it's been asked before. Or you can answer it yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

- goto settings
- search for cache
- clear browsing data
- check cached images and files (the past hour / day)
- clear browsing data

and goto your webpage and press "Ctrl + r"

Hope this helps !